# htaccess rewrite rules in Nginx: setting the rewrite path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess file I'm trying to convert into an nignx config file.

Here's my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ public/index.php?url=$1
```

And the rules I have in my nginx config file:

```
location / {
if ($request_uri !~ "-f"){
        rewrite !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ public/ break;
}
rewrite !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ public/index.php?url=$1;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
        # Move to the @missing part when the file doesn't exist
        try_files $uri @missing;

        # Fix for server variables that behave differently under nginx/$
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Include the standard fastcgi_params file included with ngingx
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;


        # Pass to upstream PHP-FPM; This must match whater you name you$
        #fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location @missing {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 break;
}
```

However, when I hit /, I get a 403 Forbidden, but I can get to /public/index.php, thus the rewrite isn't working.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `if ($request_uri !~ "-f")`-statement doesn't parse they way you want it in nginx. You're not checking for file existence but maching against the negated regex `-f`. To check for file existence in an if in nginx use `if ( -f $request_filename )`

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if for full details of nginx `if` statements

In general you want to replace the common .htaccess stanza:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    <regex>    <target>
```

with the nginx equivalent:

```
location ~* <regex> { try_files $uri $uri/ <target>;}
```

for your stated bit you'd get a nested location as follows:

```
location / {
  location ~* \.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ { try_files $uri $uri/ /public/; }
  location !~* (.*)\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?url=$1; 
  }
}
```